# Show visible sheets in combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

Hi I have the following code to show worksheets in a combobox. Sheets are automatically added to the list when it's created.

I do not want hidden sheet to be visible in the dropbox. How do I do that?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If ComboBox1.ListIndex > -1 Then Sheets(ComboBox1.Text).Select
End Sub

Private Sub Combobox1_DropbuttonClick()
    Dim xSheet As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.screenupdateing = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If ComboBox1.ListCount <> ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count Then
        ComboBox1.Clear
        For Each xSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            ComboBox1.AddItem xSheet.Name
            Next xSheet
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub Combobx1_Gotfocus()
    If ComboBox1.ListCount <> 0 Then ComboBox1.DropDown
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub Combobox1_DropbuttonClick()
    Dim xSheet As Worksheet

    '~~> Clear the bocmbobox
    ComboBox1.Clear

    '~~> Add the sheet again
    For Each xSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        '~~> Check if they are visible
        If xSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
            ComboBox1.AddItem xSheet.Name
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```