# Only show visible sheets in ComboBox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have created the following Excel-spreadsheet:

```
      A      B         C         D         E
1   Sheet1
2   Sheet2
3   Sheet5
4   Sheet6
5   Sheet8
6   Sheet9
7
```

As you can see, in `Column A` I have listed *some* of the sheets within the Excel file.

Now, I use the below VBA to get this list into a ComboBox:

```
Sub UserForm_Activate()
  ComboBox1.List = Sheet1.Range("A1:A8").Value
End Sub
```

All this works fine so far.

---

However, now it can happen that some of the sheets are not visible. Therefore, I also do not want them to appear in the `ComboBox`.

One solution I found was the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54898953/show-visible-sheets-in-combobox). However, this VBA only works over the entire Excel file but as you can see in my list above some sheets (`Sheet3, Sheet4, Sheet7`) are excluded from the list. Those sheets should also remain excluded no matter if they are visible or not.

So for example, when I make `Sheet2` and `Sheet6` invisible the list in the ComboBox should automatically be adjusted and look like this:

```
Sheet1
Sheet5
Sheet8
Sheet9
```

What do I need to change in my VBA to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below puts the sheets from the worksheet into a dynamic array and checks if it's visible, so you're not hard-coding the visible sheets. Therefore, excluding the sheets you don't want (Sheet3, Sheet4 and Sheet7) from the worksheet will also exclude them from your ComboBox.

```
 Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim sheet_list As Variant
    sheet_list = Sheet1.Range("A1:A8").Value
    'get the list of Sheets from Column A
    Dim combo_list As Variant
    combo_list = Array()
    'create and empty array

    Dim sheet_name As Variant
    For Each sheet_name In sheet_list
    'loop through sheets
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet_name).Visible Then
        'check if they are visible
            Dim ub As Long
            ub = UBound(combo_list) + 1
            ReDim Preserve combo_list(ub)
            'increment array dimension
            combo_list(ub) = sheet_name
            'add Sheet to array
        End If
    Next sheet_name

    ComboBox1.List = combo_list
    'populate the ComboBox
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Xabier, thanks a lot for your answer. When I run your code i get runtime error 9 on If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet_name).Visible Is it working on your side?

Comment: @Michi make sure that the Range `Sheet1.Range("A1:A8").Value` has values in all the cells,...

Answer (score 1):

Based on linked topic I modified the code from answer to reach what You want to achieve

```
Private Sub ChangeComboBox()
    Dim xSheet As Worksheet

    ' Clear the combobox
    ComboBox1.Clear

    ' Add the sheets again
    For Each xSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        '~~> Check if they are visible
        If xSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
            If xSheet.Name <> Sheet3.Name And xSheet.Name <> Sheet4.Name And xSheet.Name <> Sheet7.Name Then
                ComboBox1.AddItem xSheet.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Not a problem :-)